# Shift-JIS encoding for a netstandard library

Tags: .net, character-encoding, .net-core, .net-standard

In `net45`, `Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift-JIS")` works fine, but under `netstandard` it throws:

> System.ArgumentException : 'Shift-JIS' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.

The documentation it refers to mentions support via `CodePagesEncodingProvider` for .NET Core Native under UWP, but nothing for general usage with `netstandard`.

So, is it possible to use Shift-JIS encoding within a `netstandard` library?

Comment: CodePagesEncodingProvider comes with the System.Text.Encoding.CodePages package wich is not part of netstandard (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/pkg/NETStandard.Library/NETStandard.Library.packages.targets), but is part of netcore, so I guess, the answer is no, unless you write your own Encoding and EncodingProvider. The reason why System.Text.Encoding.CodePages is not part of netstandard is, I believe, because it relies today on Windows API/resources.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Reference [System.Text.Encoding.CodePages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/) package in `project.json`:

```
"System.Text.Encoding.CodePages": "4.0.1"
```

Invoke the following code **prior to** getting the Shift-JIS encoding:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

And you're good to go with:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift-JIS")
```

UPDATE:

[System.Text.Encoding.CodePages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/) is not bundled in [NETStandard.Library 1.6 package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/), but there is no problem to reference [System.Text.Encoding.CodePages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/) from your `netstandard` class library (until your class library targets `netstandard1.2` or lower).

Here is a [sample solution with the code](https://github.com/deilan-stackoverflow-samples/NetCoreShiftJisDemo). There is a class library, which targets `netstandard1.3` and a consuming console application, which targets `netcoreapp1.0` and references the class library. The class library contains the code corresponding to retrieval of `Shift-JIS` encoding. It may also be referenced and consumed from apps targeting other frameworks.

Comment: Simon Mourier already pointed to this. It's supported by .NET Core, but not `netstandard`. I'm authoring a `netstandard` library, so can't use this. I'll update the title of the question to be more clear, though this was explained in the question. Plus I already mentioned your answer in my question.

Comment: "It is not supported" does appear to be a phrase that nobody at SO ever seems to understand.   Acute reading comprehension problems are not your problem to solve, they are not real problems.  Nice answer.

Comment: @Drew Noakes I have updated the answer taking into account your comment.

Comment: @HansPassant not sure what you're getting at, sorry.

Comment: @Delian, thanks very much for your update. I'll give this a shot, but it looks perfect. You really went the extra mile with that edit. I'm sure Japanese users of my [metadata extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) appreciate your help too.

Comment: Of course you can reference it and it works fine... on a Windows platform. That doesn't means you can use it in a netstandard app.

Comment: @SimonMourier, there is no such term as "netstandard app". There are: .NET Framework app, .NET Core App, Xamarin App, UWP app, etc. .NET Standard is just for "class libraries". The way these class libraries are executed at runtime depends on the underlying runtime platform. .NET Standard itself has nothing to deal with operating systems at all. So if you read carefully the question, you will find out that it is not about operating systems, but about .NET Standard. Hence, your comment and downvote are out of scope.

Comment: Of course there is, it's an app that target the netstandard platform as defined here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library. If one wants to target his app for netstandard, it must comply with what the netstandard defines. System.Text.Encoding.CodePages is not part of the netstandard. If you use it, your app does not target the netstandard anymore, but another platform, probably you'll need at least netcore. That's the whole point of defining these platforms.

Comment: I'm still getting my head around the netstandard/.net core/etc stuff so my question is probably badly worded, but the base requirement is that folks who use .NET on platforms where `netstandard1.3` applies can use my library without it going boom at run time. From what I read about the package given here, it might not work on all platforms, which is why I asked this question in the first place. I can't find where I read that now though, unfortunately. Will wait and hope that no users file a bug report. Thanks again for your help.